# Clojure Variables and Looping

Tags: lisp, clojure, variables, loops

From googling around, I found that using `while` loops or using variables is discouraged.

Now I implemented a very simple algorithm that will read characters from an inputstream and parse accordingly: if input is `10:abcdefghej` it will parse out `10` then read next 10 bytes after the colon.

The thing I am kinda lost with is how I can refactor this so it does not rely on variables.

```
(defn decode-string [input-stream indicator]

  (with-local-vars [length (str (char indicator) )
            delimiter (.read input-stream ) 
            string (str "")
            counter 0 ]

    (while (not(= (var-get delimiter) 58 ))
       (var-set length (str (var-get length) (char (var-get delimiter)) ))
       (var-set delimiter (.read input-stream )))

    (var-set length (new BigInteger (var-get length)) )
    (var-set counter (var-get length))

    (while (not(zero? (var-get counter) ))
       (var-set string (str (var-get string) (char (.read input-stream ))  ))
       (var-set counter (dec (var-get counter))))
    (var-get string)))
```

Also, I understand that the only way to declare variables is using the `with-local-vars` keyword. Isn't it kind of unpractical to define all the variables in one block at the beginning, or am I missing some crucial point?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A bit late to this party, I suppose, but the problem is much simpler if you just treat the string as a sequence of characters and use Clojure's sequence-handling primitives:

```
(defn read-prefixed-string [stream]
  (let [s (repeatedly #(char (.read stream)))
        [before [colon & after]] (split-with (complement #{\:}) s)
        num-chars (read-string (apply str before))]
    (apply str (take num-chars after))))

user> (let [in (java.io.StringReader. "10:abcdefghij5:klmnopqrstuvwxyz")]
        (repeatedly 2 #(read-prefixed-string in)))
("abcdefghij" "klmno")
```

A summary:

- Convert the ugly, side-effectful input stream into a lazy sequence of characters, so that we can pretend it's just a string for the rest of this operation. As you can see, no more characters are actually read from the stream than are necessary to compute the result.
- Split the string into two parts: the first half characters before the first colon, and the second half whatever is left.
- Use destructuring to bind those parts to locals named `before` and `after`, and strip out the `:` while we are at it, by binding it to an unused local, named `colon` for descriptiveness.
- Read `before` to get its numerical value
- Take that many characters from `after`, and mash them all together into a string with `(apply str)`

Svante's answer is an excellent example of how to write loop-ish code with Clojure; I hope that mine is a good example of assembling the built-in functions so that they do what you need. Certainly both of these make the C solution look anything but "very simple"!

Comment: Always such great functional answers from you! +1

Comment: The decision to take a stream instead of a string also makes the function more composable.  This is a great Clojure snippet to study for a beginner.

Answer (score 18):

What you are writing is C code with lisp-like syntax (no offense intended).  Defining a style by what you *don't do* is very defining, but it is not very helpful if you don't know "well, then how else?"

By the way, I don't know what `indicator` is supposed to do.

This is how I would approach this problem:

1. The problem has two parts:  find the number of characters to read, then read that many characters.  Therefore, I would write two functions: `read-count` and `read-item`, the latter using the former.

   ```
   (defn read-count [stream]
     ;; todo
     )

   (defn read-item [stream]
     ;; todo
     )
   ```
2. `read-item` first needs to determine the number of characters to read.  For that, it uses the convenient function `read-count` that we will also define.

   ```
   (defn read-item [stream]
     (let [count (read-count stream)]
       ;; todo
       ))
   ```
3. Looping is in Clojure generally best handled by using `loop` and `recur`.  `loop` also binds variables, like `let`.  `acc` is meant to accumulate the read items, but note that it is not modified in place but re-bound each iteration.

   ```
   (defn read-item [stream]
     (loop [count (read-count stream)
            acc ""]
       ;; todo
       (recur (dec count)        ; new value for count
              (str acc c)))))    ; new value for acc
   ```
4. Now we need to do something in that loop: bind `c` to the next character, but return `acc` when `count` is 0.  `(zero? count)` is the same as `(= count 0)`.  I annotated the `if` form a bit for those unfamiliar with it.

   ```
   (defn read-item [stream]
     (loop [count (read-count stream)
            acc ""]
       (if (zero? count)                  ; condition
           acc                            ; then
           (let [c (.read stream)]        ; \
             (recur (dec count)           ;  > else
                    (str acc c)))))))     ; /
   ```
5. Now all we need is the `read-count` function.  It uses a similar loop.

   ```
   (defn read-count [stream]
     (loop [count 0]
       (let [c (.read stream)]
         (if (= c ":")
             count
             (recur (+ (* count 10)
                       (Integer/parseInt c)))))))
   ```
6. Test it on the REPL, debug, refactor.  Does `.read` really return characters?  Is there a better way to parse an integer?

I have not tested this, and I am a bit hampered by not having any experience nor deep knowledge of Clojure (I use Common Lisp mostly), but I think that it shows how to approach this kind of problem in a "lispy" way.  Note how I don't think about declaring or modifying variables.

Comment: if i understand your advice correctly i should attack a problem by trying to compose it as much in to separate functions as possible am i right?

Comment: I wouldn't say as much as possible, rather as much as sensible---you find out what concepts you can name, then encapsulate them behind that name.  However, this is just one little aspect of the above.

Answer (score 6):

Idomatic Clojure really lends it self to working with sequences. In C i tend to think in terms of variables or changing the state of a variable a bunch of times. In Clojure I think in terms of sequences. In this case I would break the problem into three layers of abstraction:

- turn the stream into a sequence of bytes.
- turn the sequence of bytes into a sequence of characters
- translate the sequence of characters into a sequence of strings.

stream to bytes:

```
defn byte-seq [rdr]  
  "create a lazy seq of bytes in a file and close the file at the end"  
  (let [result (. rdr read)]  
    (if (= result -1)  
      (do (. rdr close) nil)  
      (lazy-seq (cons result (byte-seq rdr))))))
```

bytes to chars

```
(defn bytes-to-chars [bytes]
  (map char bytes))
```

chars-to-strings [chars]

```
(defn chars-to-strings [chars]
   (let [length-str (take-wile (#{1234567890} %) chars)
         length (Integer/parseInt length-str)
         length-of-lengh (inc (count length-str)) 
         str-seq (drop length-of-length chars)]
        (lazy-seq 
          (cons
            (take length str-seq)
            (recur (drop (+ length-of-length length) chars))))))
```

This is evaluated lazily so every time the next string is needed it will be pulled from the input stream and constructed. you could use this on a network stream for instance with out having to buffer the whole stream first or worry about having the code reading from this stream worry about how it is constructed.

ps: im not at my REPL at the moment so please edit to fix any erros :)

Answer (score 3):

I'm learning Clojure myself, so take this not as guru advice but as a fellow students advice.

Clojure is a functional programming language. 
Functional programming means no loops, no variables, and no side effects. If you ever deviate from those three rules you need very good reasons for doing so and valid reasons are pretty rare.

You are obviously a very proficient programmer so take a look at this information
and you should hopefully get more of an idea of how Functional design is different than Object Oriented design.

http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Clojure_Programming/Concepts#Sequence_Functions

Also, I would recomend looking at some clojure code, here is a sample program hosted on
github.com which was written to be part of a clojure screencast-tutorial.

http://github.com/technomancy/mire/tree/master

The screencast-tutorial which the code was meant for can be found here but it is not free:

http://peepcode.com/products/functional-programming-with-clojure

(I'm not affiliated with peepcode.com in anyway).

Good luck with Clojure!